# Python3 ctypes copy pointer to ctypes.structure

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, ioctl

An ioctl the linux kernel puts a struct inside of a struct. I'm trying to figure out how to do the same with ctypes.

I receive ParentRq back from an ioctl. I want a generic way of copying the data out of Message.data into another Structure like EventID for example.

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_uint8, c_uint16, POINTER

class EventID(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('recent_addition_timestamp', c_uint8 * 4),
        ('last_recid', c_uint8 * 2),
        ('last_sw_processed_id', c_uint8 * 2),
        ('last_processed_id', c_uint8 * 2),
    ]
    _eventid_sampledata = [0x88, 0x29, 0xfd, 0x60, 0x3c, 0x02, 0xff, 0xff, 0x3c, 0x02]

class Message(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('data_len', c_uint16),
        ('data', POINTER(c_uint8))
]

class ParentRq(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('msg', Message)
    ]

p = ParentRq()
p.msg.data_len = len(EventID._eventid_sampledata)
p.msg.data = (c_uint8 * p.msg.data_len)(*EventID._eventid_sampledata)

# Proof that items got copied into the pointer correctly.
items = []
for i in range(p.msg.data_len):
    items.append(hex(p.msg.data[i]))
# items -> ['0x88', '0x29', '0xfd', '0x60', '0x3c', '0x2', '0xff', '0xff', '0x3c', '0x2']

# Copy p.msg.data into EventID
# How do I copy p.msg.data into EventID?
eid = EventID()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

There are a number of ways of achieving that, one is using *memmove*:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> class EventID(ct.Structure):
> ...     _pack_ = 1
> ...     _fields_ = [
> ...         ("recent_addition_timestamp", ct.c_uint8 * 4),
> ...         ("last_recid", ct.c_uint8 * 2),
> ...         ("last_sw_processed_id", ct.c_uint8 * 2),
> ...         ("last_processed_id", ct.c_uint8 * 2),
> ...     ]
> ...
> >>>
> >>> l = [0x88, 0x29, 0xfd, 0x60, 0x3c, 0x02, 0xff, 0xff, 0x3c, 0x02]
> >>> size = len(l)
> >>> arr = (ct.c_ubyte * size)(*l)
> >>> ptr = ct.cast(arr, ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte))  # The equivalent of Message.data (ParentRq.msg.data) instance
> [hex(ptr[i]) for i in range(size)]
> >>> ['0x88', '0x29', '0xfd', '0x60', '0x3c', '0x2', '0xff', '0xff', '0x3c', '0x2']
> >>>
> >>> eid = EventID()  # Initialize members to default values (0)
> >>>
> >>> for f, _ in EventID._fields_:
> ...     print(f, [hex(i) for i in getattr(eid, f)[:]])
> ...
> recent_addition_timestamp ['0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0']
> last_recid ['0x0', '0x0']
> last_sw_processed_id ['0x0', '0x0']
> last_processed_id ['0x0', '0x0']
> >>>
> >>> ct.memmove(ct.addressof(eid), ptr, size)
> 2361449631368
> >>>
> >>> for f, _ in EventID._fields_:
> ...     print(f, [hex(i) for i in getattr(eid, f)[:]])
> ...
> recent_addition_timestamp ['0x88', '0x29', '0xfd', '0x60']
> last_recid ['0x3c', '0x2']
> last_sw_processed_id ['0xff', '0xff']
> last_processed_id ['0x3c', '0x2']
> ```